# Prove that $F$ (the cumulative distribution function) has at most a countable number of discontinuities.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, continuity, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $F:\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$ be the distribution function associated to $\mathbb{P}$ defined by
\begin{align*}
F(x) = \mathbb{P}((-\infty,x])
\end{align*}
where $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $F$ has at most a countable number of discontinuities.

Suggestion: how many points $x\in\mathbb{R}$ can exist such that $\mathbb{P}(\{x\}) > 1/n$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$?

This is what I have tried:

For $n = 1$, there is no $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\{x\}) > 1$.

For $n = 2$, there is at most one point $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\{x\}) > 1/2$

For $n = 3$, there are at most two points $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\{x\}) > 1/3$.

In general, for $n = k$, there are at most $k - 1$ points $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\{x\}) > 1/k$.

But then I get stuck.

Can anyone help me on this?

**EDIT**

As far as I have understood, $n$ counts the number of discontinuities. For each $n$, there are $n - 1$ ways to rearrange the size of each discontinuity: there may be just $1$ value above $1/n$, two values above $1/n$, and so on. At the end, there are at most $n - 1$ values above $1/n$ which exhausts all the possibilities.

Can someone double check or improve my argument?

Comment: The set of discontinuities is therefore the union of sets with cardinalities 1, 2, 3,..... A countable union of finite set is...?

Comment: $\{x:P(\{x\})>0$ is at most countable and $P(\{x\})=0$  implies that $F$ is cacontinuoust $x$.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back @WilliamM. I was missing the definition of discontinuity in the case of cumulative distribution functions.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks for the contribution!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy just one more question: what $n$ represents in the question?

Comment: I learnt from baby rudin that any monotone function on a finite interval (a,b) has at most countable number of discontinuities (Theorem 4.30)… A trivial corollary is that it holds for infinite intervals, like the whole real line.

Comment: Many of us prefer "countable" to mean "finite or countably infinite" so that "uncountable" and "not countable" both mean "uncountably infinite". This might not be an issue in other languages.